# Injective homomorphism of $\pi_1$ of genus $3$ surface to $\pi_1$ of genus $2$ surface.

Tags: general-topology, surfaces, fundamental-groups

Let $S$ be a surface of genus $2$, and let $S'$ be a surface of genus $3$.

What is an injective homomorphism of $\pi_1(S')$ into $\pi_1(S)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two to one covering $p:S' \to S$ defined [in the answer to your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1981949/what-is-a-degree-2-covering-of-s-by-a-surface-s-of-genus-3) induces a homomoprhism
$$ p_* : \pi_1(S') \to \pi_1(S).$$

This is injective: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419137/induced-map-between-fundamental-groups-from-covering-map-is-injective)